# Як правильно говорити та писати знак близнюки чи близнята

Tags: вибір-слова

Коли говоримо про знаки зодіаку, як правильно вживати близнюки чи близнята?

В Google пошуку єобидва варіанти [близнюки](https://www.google.com.ua/search?ei=rkr1W52yB7OOmgWNj56IAQ&q=%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%20%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%B8&oq=%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%20%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0l2j0i22i30l8.28704.29553..31603...0.0..0.97.373.4......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i203.NDZYPsszJQs) та [близнята](https://www.google.com.ua/search?ei=3kv1W_P_F4idsAGDzr_AAg&q=%20%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0&oq=%20%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i67j0i7i10i30j0i7i30l4j0i7i10i30l2j0i7i30l2.13230.13230..13759...0.0..0.90.90.1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.xQiW86QOH3M)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Головна астрономічна обсерваторія НАН подає переклад GEMINI - Близнята

https://www.mao.kiev.ua/calendar/constellations.htm